# How to ask for a leave to attend a job interview

Tags: professionalism

Well the question itself it's pretty self explanatory, right now i have a job, but i'm looking for something better for my needs, the thing is how i'm supposed to ask (professionally) permission to attend a job interview in a normal day of work

Comment: I just tell my work "I have an appointment." I make sure to always not specify exactly what kind of appointment, be it doctor, dentist, or job interview, so they won't ever take particular notice of my being vague when it's an appointment of any type that I don't want to discuss.

Comment: If there is a chance they ask an 'appointment for what?', what i could say? personal matters?

Comment: It's not very likely they'd ask, since medical appointments and such are not the employer's business, so generally people won't pry.  If they do ask, just tell them you'd rather keep it private.

Answer (score 2):

> how i'm supposed to ask (professionally) permission to attend a job
>   interview in a normal day of work

You could request a vacation day. Or plan a series of interviews for your already-scheduled vacation week.

Some companies offer "personal days". If your company does, you could request one.

Many people choose to call in sick. While that's not honest, it is what happens often in my part of the world (US).

Some people indicate that they have an appointment to attend, and leave out the details.

Comment: (Hypothetically) how would it play out if a person were to state upfront why they wish to be absent?

Comment: @Riorank, that generally only works out ok if you are part of a general layoff and they are giving you time at work to look for another job such as when a contract is ending on 1 Oct.

Comment: Makes sense. But wouldn't it be deceptive for a person to utilize a sick day, personal day, vacation day? Let me rephrase that. I understand the need to lie. (Tell the truth, premature termination etc) But wouldn't the employer figure out 2+2 if a person were to suddenly resign a week after a [insert adjective] day? Effectively, would there be any merits in being upfront about it? (In a non-general layoff setting)

Comment: A personal day or vacation day is *YOURS.*  You may do with it whatever you wish, and you don't have to answer to anyone (except maybe your spouse) about what you did that day.

Comment: However, yes, using a sick day would be dishonest. I'd take an unpaid day off in preference to that.